# Redirect if alert button is not pushed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I force to redirect the page even if the `alert` box button is not pushed?

I have code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect()
{
window.location="../index.php";
}
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);
alert("You will be redirected to a new page in 5 seconds"); 
window.location="../index.php"; 
</script>
```

Now I have to push the button to be redirected. What I want to do is: if visitor doesn't push OK button in 5 seconds he's forced to `../index.php` and if he push OK button system redirects him immediately to `../index.php`

Comment: You can't. Use a custom modal dialog box rather than the browser default.

Answer (score 0):

you cant achieve it with alert or confirm or prompt because all of these freezes the browser so further Javascript will not execute.
use this

```js
setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);
function Redirect()
{
window.location="../index.php";
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  
  Your text
  <button class="closebtn" onclick="Redirect();">OK</button> 
</div
><style>
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hey, `alert` will always return `undefined`. So redirect will be happened immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the single quotes from the function name

```
function Redirect()
{
window.location="../index.php";
}
setTimeout(Redirect(), 5000);
```